# How to share session between 2 users privately like in online chess games in php?

Tags: php, html, session, chat

I want that 2 users can have a private chat or play a game privately. How should i use sessions to keep the shared data between the 2 users private such as chat data or any other data like their chess game data that they are privately playing.

Is it possible with session or is there a better way ?

Comment: With databases -> `owner_user_id | chat_partner_user_id | message | timestamp | etc..` -> `SELECT message, timestamp FROM my_chat_table WHERE owner_user_id = YOUR_USER_ID OR chat_partner_user_id = YOUR_USER_ID`...etc.etc

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use one session for two/many users because in future you'll maybe want to store data in session that should be shared between users (maybe the username, if you implement an login system).

You should create a table in your database for each case. If you want to implement an one-to-one chat you should create a table like below to store the messages person1 is writing to person2.

Table `chat_messages`:

```
from_user_id | to_user_id | message               | timestamp             | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3            | 6          | 'Are you there?'      | '2016-01-08 02:00:00' | ...
9            | 2          | 'Hello, this is Maik' | '2016-01-08 03:45:00' | ...
2            | 9          | 'Hi Maik, how are u?' | '2016-01-08 03:45:10' | ...
```

There should also be a table for storing the `user` information including one unique identifier (e.g. `user_id`). The `user_id` will be used in table `chat_messages` for referencing to the users. In your session you'll only store the userId of the according user.

It means: Each users has its own session and its own dataset in the `users` table.

Comment: yes i understood it but what about a game like tic tac toe or chess how should i store that in database and keep it private between 2 users ?

Comment: In that case you'll have two tables `game` and `game_move` to store the games and all moves the players are doing. To keep it private you have the possibility to add two columns to table `game` (e.g. `player1` and `player2`) and only allow entering the game when the current user (it is stored in the session) matches to `player1` or `player2`.